# How to make virtual functions of a super class overrideable for grandchildren in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, virtual-functions

Hey guys here is some code I am going to run, issue is it doesn't work the way I intend to. I am unable to figure out what's wrong with it. I am c++ noob please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

/**
 * Super class
 */
class Shape
{
protected:
    int _dimensions;
public:
    Shape() : _dimensions{0}
    {};
    Shape(int dims) : _dimensions{dims}
    {};

    virtual double getArea() {};
    // Because some shapes have no volume.  
    virtual double getVolume() {};  

    void setDimensions(int dim)
    {
        this->_dimensions = dim;
    };
    int getDimensions()
    {
        return this->_dimensions;
    };
};


/** 
 * Extended classes
 */
class TwoDimensionalShape : public Shape
{
public: 
    TwoDimensionalShape() : Shape{2}
    {};
    // This should throw an error
    double getVolume() {
        throw logic_error("This shape ain't got area!");
    };  
};

class ThreeDimensionalShape : public Shape
{
public: 
    ThreeDimensionalShape() : Shape{3} {};
};


/**
 * Final Concrete classes extending extended classes
 */
class Circle : public TwoDimensionalShape
{
protected:
    double _radius;
public:
    Circle(double r) : _radius{r}
    {};
    double getArea()
    {
        // pi*r^2
        return M_PI * pow(_radius, 2);
    }
};

class Square : public TwoDimensionalShape
{
protected:
    double _side;
public:
    Square(double s) : _side{s}
    {}
    double getArea()
    {
        // s^2
        return pow(_side, 2);
    }
};

class Triangle : public TwoDimensionalShape
{
protected:
    double _base, _height;
public:
    Triangle(double b, double h) : _base{b}, _height{h}
    {};
    double getArea()
    {
        // b*h/2
        return _base * _height / 2;
    }
};

class Sphere : public ThreeDimensionalShape
{
protected:
    double _radius;
public:
    Sphere(double r) : _radius{r}
    {}
    double getArea()
    {
        cout << 4 * M_PI * pow(_radius, 2) << endl;
        return 4 * M_PI * pow(_radius, 2);
    }
    double getVolume()
    {
        return (4/3) * M_PI * pow(_radius, 3);
    }
};

class Cube : public ThreeDimensionalShape
{
protected:
    double _side;
public:
    Cube(double s) : _side{s}
    {};
    double getArea()
    {
        // surface area = 6*a^2
        return 6 * pow(_side, 2);
    }
    double getVolume()
    {
        // a^3
        return pow(_side, 3);
    }
};

class Tetrahedron : public ThreeDimensionalShape
{
protected:
    double _side;
public:
    Tetrahedron(double s) : _side{s}
    {};
    double getArea()
    {
        // sqrt(3)*a^2
        return sqrt(3) * pow(_side, 2);
    }
    double getVolume()
    {
        // a^3/6sqrt(2)
        return pow(_side, 3) / (6 * sqrt(2));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Shape arr[2];
    arr[0] = Circle{10};
    arr[1] = Sphere{10};

    // This one is accessing the right method.
    cout << "Area of circle: " << arr[0].getArea() << endl; 
    // This one should access the parent, but accesses the grand parent!
    // even if it is overridden in parent.
    cout << "Volume of circle: " << arr[0].getVolume() << endl; 

    // Both of these are accessing methods on grand parent rather than their own!!
    cout << "Area of sphere: " << arr[1].getArea() << endl;
    cout << "Volume of sphere: " << arr[1].getVolume() << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why the array methods keep accessing the grand parent functions in the last three lines, but the right method on the first.

Comment: You are experiencing *Object slicing*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: owh so, me trying to store grandchildren in superclass object array is the issue?

Comment: owh, thanks for the tip. I have been watching some java tutorials too lately so, a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing *Object Slicing*. The portion of your code below does that:

```
Shape arr[2];
arr[0] = Circle{10};
arr[1] = Sphere{10};
```

Each of the assignments above invokes the copy assignment operator of `Shape` and [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) off objects of the subclass. You can achieve your intention by using references or pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<Shape> arr[2];
arr[0] = std::make_unique<Circle>(10);
arr[1] = std::make_unique<Sphere>(10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example.

Comment: class std::unique_ptr<Shape>’ has no member named ‘getArea’

Comment: @PrimeHero, wrapped in a `std::unique_ptr`, you access the `Shape`'s members with `->` not `.`. Example `arr[0]->getArea()`

Comment: sorry, thanks a lot got the answers! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of object slicing. You need to put your objects as pointers, preferably as `std::unique_ptr<>` into your array - or again preferably a `std::vector<>`

Try this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// ...

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> vec(2);
    vec[0] = std::make_unique<Circle>(10);
    vec[1] = std::make_unique<Sphere>(10);

    // This one is accessing the right method.
    cout << "Area of circle: " << vec[0]->getArea() << endl;
   // This one should access the parent, but accesses the grand parent!
    // even if it is overridden in parent.
    cout << "Volume of circle: " << vec[0]->getVolume() << endl;

    // Both of these are accessing methods on grand parent rather than their own!!
    cout << "Area of sphere: " << vec[1]->getArea() << endl;
    cout << "Volume of sphere: " << vec[1]->getVolume() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Vector seems good, I'll go with a vector.